# How can i make i custom font awesome icon?

Tags: html, css, odoo, tiktok

I want to add the TikTok [icon](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/tiktok?style=brands) from font awesome v5. I am currently developing an application with Odoo in which the v4 of font awesome is already integrated. In v4 the TikTok icon does not exist. Can anyone give me an idea of how I can make my own icon without importing the whole v5 library?

Comment: I actually don’t know the Odoo framework, but do you not have the ability to show a SVG: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cib-tiktok_(CoreUI_Icons_v1.0.0).svg

Comment: With showing the SVG in my HTML will I have an option to style it with attributes such as font size and color as I do have with the font awesome icons?

Comment: You can normally import a SVG in graphic tools like Illustrator or Affinity Designer and recolor and resize it. But the size is probably different than that what you have with an imported font. It just needs some more effort and try’s until it does everything fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Odoo but try adding this to your code:

```html
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="tiktok" class="svg-inline--fa fa-tiktok fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M448,209.91a210.06,210.06,0,0,1-122.77-39.25V349.38A162.55,162.55,0,1,1,185,188.31V278.2a74.62,74.62,0,1,0,52.23,71.18V0l88,0a121.18,121.18,0,0,0,1.86,22.17h0A122.18,122.18,0,0,0,381,102.39a121.43,121.43,0,0,0,67,20.14Z"></path></svg>
```

[image: Here's how to download SVG'S from Font Awesome:]